# Rest Assured - How to include cookies in redirects?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a problem in rest assured to pass SESSION_ID from one request to another when the request is redirected. Any idea how to do it? I tried this, but it does not work.

```
        var responseWithConfig = given()
            .config(new RestAssuredConfig().httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().setParam(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY)))
            .when().redirects().follow(true).get("www.example.com");
```

Comment: Cookies are bound to domain/ip.Whats the problem here?

Comment: The thing is that when I send this get request:
http://localhost/xx/xx/xx?client_id=XXX&grant_type=XXX&response_type=XXX&redirect_uri=XXX
 I get SESSION _ID in response and I am automatically redirected to the login page. When I do it throw web browser, SESSION_ID follow redirection and request contains SESSION_ID and it is possible to log in.  However, in Rest Assured, cookies do not follow redirection by default, so on log in page there is now session id and it is not possible to log in.